# Is this a bug in DirectX9 Effect Compiler? "Invalid input semantics - POSITIONT0"

Tags: c++, directx, shader, hlsl, effects

I am trying to compile a very simple Effect Shader targeting DirectX9 and shader model 2. I am trying to pass in directly the screen coords for the vertex Positions instead of multiplying by a world, view, and projection matrices so I use the POSITIONT semantic instead of the POSTION0 semantic in the VertexShaderInput structure. However when I try to compile the shader using

```
fxc.exe /Od /Zi /T fx_2_0 /Fo simple.fxo simple.fx
```

I get the following error: "error X4502: Invalid input semantics - POSITIONT0"

It seems to be automatically adding a 0 to the end of the semantic for some reason. This seems like I bug to me because POSITIONT is clear described as a valid input semantic here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509647(v=vs.85).aspx#PS

and it is the only one that does not allow extra integers to be appended at the end of the semantic.

EDIT: I have just discovered that if I change POSITIONT to POSITIONT1 it works fine. This seem counter to what the documentation above describes.

Contents of simple.fx:

```
struct VertexShaderInput
{
  float4 Position : POSITIONT;
  float4 Color : COLOR0;
};

struct VertexShaderOutput
{
  float4 Position : POSITION0;
  float4 Color : COLOR0;
};

VertexShaderOutput VertexShaderFunction(VertexShaderInput input)
{ 
  VertexShaderOutput output;
  output.Position = input.Position;
  output.Color = input.Color;
  return output;
}


float4 PixelShaderFunction(VertexShaderOutput input) : COLOR0
{
  return input.Color;
}

technique Ambient
{
  pass Pass1
  {
    VertexShader = compile vs_2_0 VertexShaderFunction();
    PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 PixelShaderFunction();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For legacy Direct3D9 there is a special `D3DDECLUSAGE_POSITIONT` which means to just skip vertex processing. Therefore, you can only use `POSITIONT` in the PIXEL SHADER input--i.e. it can't be used in a VERTEX SHADER at all.

Change your shader to use `POSITION` or `POSITION0`.

Comment: I am targeting DX3D9 and I did use the D3DECLUSAGE_POSITIONT in my vertex deceleration.  I have been experimenting more and for some reason if I use POSITIONT1 it seems to work fine. Which is really weird since the documentation  I linked to above seems to imply that you can't use numbered POSITIONT

Comment: ``D3DECLUSAGE_POSITIONT`` in the vertex declaration means to not use a vertex shader... It's a weird special-case that dates back to the fixed-function pipeline. Best to just use ``D3DECLUSAGE_POSITION``, ``POSITION`` and then use the 'pass-through' vertex shader you already defined.